# Keyboard shortcut for cut video AND sound at current position in premiere cs5.5

Tags: editing, premiere

I know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> which cuts video at current position, but which shortcut will allow to cut video AND sound?

Answer (score 2):

the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> didnt work for me for some reason.